# Dependence of Lorentz factor on only a component of velocity

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, momentum, velocity, inertial-frames

In cases of two- or three-dimensional space, why doesn't the Lorentz factor of a component of 3-space momentum depend on only the corresponding component of velocity? That is, why isn't there, for example, $$p_y=\frac{mv_y}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v_y^2}{c^2}}}?$$
I think I've studied only the introduction to SR, so ideally I need an introductory-level/intuitive explanation with not so advanced math details. If it is not possible, I need a 'step-by-step procedure', which may be just a straight explanation or a set of references to hierarchical sources.

Comment: This is either a very naive question, or a very deep one. Search for "Lorentz boost". Even Wikipedia is good for a start.

Comment: I consider it a reasonably deep question. I think the OP does not yet grasp that the equations of physics are relations between geometric objects that, being coordinate-system-independent, have to have specific transformations under changes of coordinates. From this viewpoint, the OP’s equation cannot possibly be correct because it equates a vector to a non-vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a spacetime interval:
$\Delta \tau = \sqrt{\Delta t^2 - \Delta x^2 - \Delta y^2 - \Delta z^2}$

$$\frac{d\tau}{dt} = \frac{\Delta t - v_x\Delta x - v_y\Delta y - v_z\Delta z}{\sqrt{\Delta t^2 - \Delta x^2 - \Delta y^2 - \Delta z^2}}$$

Because the spatial coordinates are function of t. Dividing by $\Delta t$ numerator and denominator and letting deltas go to zero:

$$\frac{d\tau}{dt} = \frac{1 - v_x^2 - v_y^2 - v_z^2}{\sqrt{1 - v_x^2 - v_y^2 - v_z^2}} = \sqrt{1 - v_x^2 - v_y^2 -  v_z^2}$$

$$\frac{dt}{d\tau} = \left(\frac{d\tau}{dt}\right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - v^2}}$$

4-momentum is the result of the derivative of the position vector (multiplied by m). For example the y coordinate:

$$m\frac{dy}{d\tau} = m\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{d\tau} = \frac{mv_y}{\sqrt{1 - v^2}}$$

So it must be $v^2$ and not $v_y^2$ inside the square root.

Comment: Why do we take the derivative of the position vector with respect to the proper time? Different observers get different momenta anyway, so why do we take the same time for all of them? Also, it is like we are dividing own position by not own time, I don't get it((

Comment: The whole purpose of relativity is that the laws of nature are the same for inertial observers. The conventional momentum vector, where the velocities are derivatives with respect to $t$ instead of $\tau$ doesn't follow this rule. $\mathbf p$, if it was defined that way would not be conserved for different frames after a collision.

Comment: Ironically, the question about the Lorentz factor popped out when I was watching a video about the need of the factor for the very conservation of momentum. So, I'm satisfied by this explanation about the derivative to only some degree. I know the postulate, but I'm just not comfortable with this explanation( Can you word/explain it differently, please? A different explanation may be the silliest one, but I may accept it fully, believe me)

Comment: Maybe the best way is if you set and solve a simple elastic collision problem in one dimension. Then, using the rule of addition of velocities of relativity, transform all the bodies velocities for a moving frame. The conclusion is: we say that our classical momentum $m(dx/dt)$ is conserved because our velocities are too low to measure its variation.

Comment: Sorry, I've failed( There was a conservation in Newtonian sense: the velocity addition was, of course, different, but in the end I didn't encounter the need to include the gamma factor. Can you show?

Comment: OK, but it is another question. Can you ask it and show your trial?

Comment: It seems, now my concern is different. If you insist, I can show my work later, but for now let's assume that I understand how the momentum is conserved. A question is "Why?". Is Newton's 3rd law true here or it is modified too? If it's true, why? I just can't imagine why the momentum should be conserved for those high speeds.

Comment: I've now looked through some answers here. So, I should just accept that the conservation laws are just experimental facts so far for all of physics, or/and that they are true by the Noether's theorem? No other ways? And in that case the only form of the relativistic momentum is the above one, right?

Answer (score 2):

> why doesn't the Lorentz factor of a component of 3-space momentum depend on only the corresponding component of velocity?

Because that definition of $\mathbf{p}$ wouldn’t transform as a 3D vector should under rotations. Since the velocity $\mathbf{v}$ is a vector under rotations, the Lorentz factor $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ needs to be a rotational scalar, constructed from $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v}$.